# Failed to filter array of data based on there condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I want to retrieve based on their list of IDs given. There is a list of ids I used inside my controller I want to retrieve all the objects array based on the given list of ids to me here is a prototype of my database record how it looks like

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("630a2e258bb6b10016ca68f1"),
        "deviceId": "42925f6a6eec14d8",
        "personId": ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb"),
        "createdAt": 1661611557637,
        "updatedAt": 1661611557637,
    },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("630a2e258bb6b10016ca68f1"),
        "deviceId": "42925f6a6eec14d8",
        "personId": ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb"),
        "createdAt": 1661611557637,
        "updatedAt": 1661611557637,
    },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("630a2e258bb6b10016ca68f1"),
        "deviceId": "42925f6a6eec14d8",
        "personId": ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb"),
        "createdAt": 1661611557637,
        "updatedAt": 1661611557637,
    },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("630a2e258bb6b10016ca68f1"),
        "deviceId": "42925f6a6eec14d8",
        "personId": ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb"),
        "createdAt": 1661611557637,
        "updatedAt": 1661611557637,
    }
]
```

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
getData: async function (req, res) {

    // var db = Device.getDatastore().manager;

    let ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

    let usersID = [
      "62f79104bb4b3d0016260b88",
      "62f925a3bcbc910016a360b6",
      "630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb",
    ];

    var devices = await Device.find({
      personId: {
        $in: [...usersID],
      },
    });
    if (!devices) {
      return res.badRequest("Please specify search criteria");
      // var devices = await Device.find();
    }
    return res.successResponse(
      devices,
      200,
      null,
      true,
      "${devices.size()} roles are found."
    );
  },
```

Comment: you need to convert string ids to object id by `let usersID = [ObjectId("62f79104bb4b3d0016260b88"), ObjectId("62f925a3bcbc910016a360b6"), ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb")];`
`

Comment: Not sure why are you spreading the array, just to add it another array? You can just do `$in : usersID` and of course you will have to convert to ObjectID as @turivishal mentioned. You can run a `.map` to convert all of them in one loop. In ideal world ID's should already be in ObjectID format

Comment: @Shivam I tried both of your suggestion its giving the same error `"Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by `personId`: Unrecognized modifier (`$in`) within provided constraint for `personId`."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregate to change de objectId to string and get the result you want.

here is an example:

```
 const devices = await Device.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "personId": {
        "$toString": "$personId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "personId": {
        $in: [
          "62f79104bb4b3d0016260b88",
          "62f925a3bcbc910016a360b6",
          "630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or:

```
 const devices = await Device.find(
  {"personId": {
        $in: [
          ObjectId("62f79104bb4b3d0016260b88"),
          ObjectId("62f925a3bcbc910016a360b6"),
          ObjectId("630a2e218bb6b10016ca68eb")
        ]
      }
    }
).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not working the result is empty object

Comment: hmm, could you share how are you doing it, because I test it and work here https://mongoplayground.net/p/6N2sX_HVI5I

Comment: is there any other way to get the data I wanted without adding another field

Comment: you got personId as ObjectId to match with the array of string you must convert the objectId to string or the string to objectId, but if your problem it the personIdSTR field you could remplace it with personId. I will edit my answer to show you how to achieve it.

Comment: Yes thanks I tried in the playground it works but some how its not working in my code

Comment: Make sure you have record in your device collection with the personId you are providing, another thing it that you got duplicated _id in your record example.

Comment: No, I didn't give the total data i just a few of the fields and copied them multiple times pasted them. Actually, there are 18 fields that will confuse others so I remove a few fields from the question