# Mongo and mongoose $match _id in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a frontend in React and a backend in express and node.

From FE i am calling an API on the server:

```
 const { data: autotaskItems } = useApiCall({
    url: `api/endpoint`,
    method: 'post',
    payload: {
      filter: {
        _id: {
          $in: ["id1","id2"],
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

on the server:

```js
router.post('/config-items/find', async (req, res) => {


  const { filter } = req.body

  // ConfigItem.find({ ...filter })

  // .then(result => {
  //   res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: result });
  // })

  ConfigItem.aggregate([
    { $match: { ...filter } 
  }])
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: result });
    })
```

But this doesn't work. I have found that aggregate doesn't "support" automatic conversion of ObjectId to string. If I have used find() and spread filter like above this will work just fine. However, I do need to use aggregate as I have a couple of lookups there too.

Anyone can help, please?

Also, if possible i would like to keep structure with spreading the filter object for match

Thank you

Comment: This answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549235/19027584

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19027584/martinez)'s answer, this was resolved by the following:

Nice and simple :-)

```js
  ConfigItem.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
//rest of the query
```